# How to import 1500 products into WP eCommerce with Custom Meta information?

Tags: wordpress, csv, import, custom-fields

I have a CSV file of products I need to import with the Custom Meta information but from what I have seen, the CSV examples only covers a few of the product details to import and not the Custom Meta information.

I have looked into a plugin I found by Visser Labs and although it looks like the thing I need, it is a super expensive and I am hoping there is someone who has done something similar for far cheaper?

Otherwise, if I have overlooked something and there is a simpler method, please let me know?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This [LINK](http://www.analogrithems.com/rant/portfolio/wordpress-ecommerce-data-feeder/) describes the accepted import categories, as well as a Wordpress Plugin to import a CSV for eCommerce.

Best part of this page is the clarification of import fields acceptable by WP eCommerce.

As for importing custom meta:

```
meta_* - Custom meta data can also be included by creating a column 
that has meta_ prefixed to it.  For example if you want to have a 
custom meta field called brand associated to your product you can 
create a column called meta_Brand.
```